# JsonPath check hashMap values are present using Gatling?

Tags: scala, hashmap, gatling, hamcrest, jsonpath

I want to compare some `<key,values>` in the jsonPath passed as `HashMap<String,String>()` data. How can we achieve it in gatling check ?

```
  val hashMap = new HashMap[String,String]()
  hashMap.put("foo", "bar")
```

OR can I simply check something like this ?

```
for (String key <- keyValue){
.check(jsonPath("$." + key.(is(hashMap.get(key)))))
}
```

OR

```
.check(jsonPath.containsAll(hashMap.keySet), jsonPath.containsAll(hashMap.valueSet))
```

Or can I use **hamcrest** or some other to compare this HashMap with JsonPath.

```
.exec(http("my testl").post("/some_url").headers(common_header).body(bodyPayLoad).
asJSON.check(status.is(200)).check(jsonPath("$",Matchers.hasItems(hashMap)).saveAs("response"))).exec(session => {
                val responseValue = session.get("response").asOption[String]
                println(testCase + " REST API Response :" + responseValue)
                session
              }).pause(10)
```

How can I achive it?